# IAM user is not authorized to perform: application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-iam

I am trying to add autoscaling to a cluster. However I encountered the following error:

[image]

I have already added the IAM user to these new security groups:

[image]

and[image]

Altogether this user has the following permissions:

```
 AmazonSQSFullAccess
  AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
  AmazonS3FullAccess
  CloudWatchFullAccess
  AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
  CloudFrontFullAccess
  AmazonEC2FullAccess
  CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
  AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess
  AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser
  IAMReadOnlyAccess
  AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole
```

What did I miss?

EDIT:

I  have added

**AutoScalingFullAccess**

and

**ApplicationAutoScalingForAmazonAppStreamAccess**

but no cigar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to add the following custom policy to one of my permission groups

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "application-autoscaling:*",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html#auto-scaling-IAM

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above we need the add the IAM pass role to the policy. So the policy should look like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "application-autoscaling:*",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
            ],
            "Resource": "<RESOURCE-ARN>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the reference URL:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html][1]